# Error executing an aspx file using Server.Execute

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a code in say **SaidFile.aspx** which gets executed when the page loads. When that code is executed, a pdf file is generated and stored on the server. I am trying to execute that page while in the context of another file but using the following code:

```
Server.Execute(String.Format("~/SaidFile.aspx&id={0}", sID))
```

I get the following error instead.

```
    System.Web.HttpException: Error executing child request for ~/~/SaidFile.aspx&id=32. 
---> System.Web.HttpException: No http handler was found for request type 'POST' at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapIntegratedHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig, Boolean convertNativeStaticFileModule) 
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace 
--- at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) 
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path) 
at ASP.modules_onlinepayments_controls_paymentprocessgeneric_ascx.processPayment() 
in D:\blah\blah\blah\Blah.ascx: line 138
```

Comment: Can you copy the whole exception or at least the message part of the exception? A part of stack trace is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have used wrong URL for you GET params: `&` instead of `?`.

According to MSDN path should be either absolute or relative to currently executed ASPX, so it's better to try this:

```cs
Server.Execute(String.Format(Server.MapPath("/SaidFile.aspx")+"?id={0}", sID))
```